# Wrong number calls to my business from Siri

Tags: iphone, numbers, siri

For the last 4 months we have been receiving at least five wrong number calls every single day. All calls are coming through one particular number even though we have four numbers on our website. Every time I ask the caller how they got the number they say they were using Siri.

My first thought was that there was some sort of weird forwarding happening, so I contacted our VOIP provider, ring central, they said everything looked good to them.

I contacted AppleCare and they informed me that Siri gets results from multiple sources. Primarily Google.

I've done a few experiments

First, I paused Google ads for about 2 weeks while one of our contractors was out of town but we were still getting wrong number calls. So that rules out our ads. Which is fantastic news since these wrong numbers are not costing us any money.

I also removed the particular number from our Google listings all together. Wrong numbers kept coming.

Apple maps seems another source of information as well so I created a new business connect profile to see if that would resolve the issue. It has not.

I did some research to find out other data sources for Siri so I also checked yellow pages, Yahoo business, Yelp and others.

When I Google our phone number I'm not seeing any incorrect listings. I'm racking my brain trying to figure this out and I'm just spending tons of time on this.

The businesses that people claim to be trying to call have nothing to do with our business and nothing to do with each other.

I get calls for beer distributors, hospitals, UPS, florists, all types of businesses.

This is super annoying and making me less inclined to answer the phone if I'm busy or with another client.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't see how anyone but Apple could fix this.

Comment: Thank you, I'll reach out and post results here.

Comment: Instead of contacting Apple directly I thought it may be a good idea to create Apple Business Connect profiles for each of my listings. A few days later the wrong number calls stopped.